# Multiple sub classes inheriting one instance of their super class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following example:

```
import uuid

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4().hex

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.print_id()

    def print_id(self):
        print(self.id)

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.print_id()

    def print_id(self):
        print(self.id)
```

We have class B and C that are inheriting A. Once B or C are instantiated, they will print the unique ID created in the super class. The issue I am running into here is that each time B or C is instantiated, there is a brand new id created for class A. I would like to print/use the SAME ID for both class B and C. In other words, I only want to have one instance of class A to be used for B and C. Without involving any sort of logic surrounding singletons, how can I achieve this? How can class C know that class B has already initialized class A, therefore an ID already exists? I am attempting to create a base class that is initialized only once, and that ID is inherited by all the sub classes. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot inherit from instances, but from classes. The way your class is written, a new id gets created for every instance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for this note. I have noticed this. If I would like to derive from a base that only creates this ID once, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You essentially want each class to have a unique id, where every instance of those classes shares the same id? I'm still not exactly sure what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python)

e.g.

```py
class A:
    static_id = uuid.uuid4().hex

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The rest of the code will be the same.

I changed the name of the `id` member, because it shadowed the name of a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

(This solution smells to me a little, but I do not understand your problem enough to suggest anything better).

Comment: There's nothing static about a class attribute, in the sense that C/C++ use the term.

Comment: @chepner can you elaborate?

Comment: I would defer to the explanations of `static` given in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572547/1126841).